# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 6.x and passport package.
I used api_token in App\User  before installing this package.
Now I want to authenticate Users  with passport package but I am experiencing this error,

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

This is my gaurd:

```
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

This is my authController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    private $successStatus=200;
    public function login(){
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use `session` driver. `attempt` method come from SessionGuard

Comment: @TsaiKoga see this url please https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: However, passport's guard has no `attempt` method,  you can try it like this: `Auth::guard('api')->attempt(['...']); Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['...']);`.  Here is [SessionGuard's attempt-method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L345). [Request Guard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/RequestGuard.php) and [TokenGuard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php)

Comment: I think the link u provided is using `'defaults' => ['guard' => 'web'...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my controller to this and the problem was resolved

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){



        $user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

        if($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('tp_@1')-> accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success],200);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>'invalid username or pass !'], 401);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You may be having the following configuration:**

change your `auth.php`

`passport` to `token`

```
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

Comment: ok thanks but , are u sure ?  i wanna using passport package !